# FFMPEG - Non-monotonous DTS

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

When I use FFMPEG to convert a video from MP4 to M3U8, using the following command,

```
ffmpeg -i op.mp4  -b:v 128k -flags -global_header -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list op.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts op%05d.ts
```

I get the below warning :

```
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 347527, current: 346508; changing to 347528. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

The M3U8 is generated, but only audio is coming up on quicktime player.

Both the Sample MP4 and M3U8 are available [here](https://drive.google.com/a/recordtv.com/?tab=mo#folders/0B_x2LZVyvfSWOXBaYjFzbEpTZDA)

So, I would like to know

1. Reason behind this error. Is it a corrupt mp4 or problem during conversion. The m3u8 is playable is not playable on quicktime properly. Only audio comes up, no video.
2. How can I possibly fix this

Complete FFMPEG Console Output :

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-06-06-c51654f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  6 2013 12:54:24 with gcc 4.6.3 (GCC) 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 35.100 / 52. 35.100
  libavcodec     55. 15.100 / 55. 15.100
  libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 75.101 /  3. 75.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'op.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.010000, bitrate: 679 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x364 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:91], 590 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[segment @ 0x32e1d60] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[segment @ 0x32e1d60] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, segment, to 'op%05d.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 640x364 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:91], q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg2video)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> mp2)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[segment @ 0x32e1d60] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 347527, current: 346508; changing to 347528. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  109 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.29 bitrate=N/A dup=14 drop=0  frame=  151 fps=0.0 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=N/A dup=14 drop=0    
video:350kB audio:96kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.004823%
```

With vsync and async options, the error that appears is "Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers". Here is the console output :

```
ffmpeg -i op.mp4  -b:v 128k -flags -global_header -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list nop.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts nop%05d.ts  
ffmpeg version git-2013-06-06-c51654f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  6 2013 12:54:24 with gcc 4.6.3 (GCC) 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 35.100 / 52. 35.100
  libavcodec     55. 15.100 / 55. 15.100
  libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 75.101 /  3. 75.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'op.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.010000, bitrate: 679 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x364 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:91], 590 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[segment @ 0x3bf3d60] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[segment @ 0x3bf3d60] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, segment, to 'nop%05d.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 640x364 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:91], q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg2video)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> mp2)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[segment @ 0x3bf3d60] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 347527, current: 346508; changing to 347528. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  119 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.68 bitrate=N/A dup=14 drop=0  frame=  151 fps=0.0 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=N/A dup=14 drop=0    
video:350kB audio:96kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.004823%
```

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Edited to add the complete ffmpeg console output

Comment: What happens if you add the parameters `-vsync 1 -async 1` ?

Comment: Updated above the console output with vsync and async options

Comment: Does this happen for any .mp4 file?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. M3U8 is a playlist specification, not a video format. Please provide more details on your  desired use case.

Comment: There are like 5 people on this planet who know the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your CSI clip converted with non-monotonous DTS message as well. I was able to play the MP4 clip okay in VLC, but ffplay hiccuped at the end. I'm not sure what that means.

`ffmpeg -i op.mp4  -b:v 128k -flags -global_header -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list op.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts op%05d.ts`

Just get a newer version of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Yours is from June 2013. Mine from March 2014 worked just fine. The mp4 plays fine for me on VLC. The individual .ts files played okay for me as well.

```
C:\temp>dir op*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is xxx-xxx

 Directory of C:\temp

10/07/2014  08:52 PM               169 op.m3u8
10/07/2014  08:51 PM           509,425 op.mp4
10/07/2014  08:52 PM           404,764 op00000.ts
10/07/2014  08:52 PM           148,520 op00001.ts
               4 File(s)      1,062,878 bytes
```

the op.m3u8 created the segment in 4 seconds increments until the file was completely processed.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXTINF:4.120000,
op00000.ts
#EXTINF:1.960000,
op00001.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Answer (score 1):

That mp4 is only 6 seconds long, and the audio stream is a different length than the video, I was able to sync the two and get rid of the DTS errors by doing the following though:

```
ffmpeg -i op.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.11 -t 00:00:06.00 -vn -y op.wav

ffmpeg -i op.mp4 -ss 0.010000 -t 00:00:06 -vcodec rawvideo -an -y op.avi

ffmpeg -i op.avi -i op.wav -b:v 590k -b:a 130k -t 00:00:06 -y op_fixed.mp4
```

This basically recreates the mp4 and fixes some minor corruption issues while making both streams the same length.

Also, your command line doesn't need the two -map parameters, and neither of the codecs from the original mp4 support global headers, besides which I don't imagine you'd need them anyway. The following should complete without errors after completing the steps I listed above:

```
ffmpeg -i op_fixed.mp4 -b:v 128k -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list op.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts op%05d.ts
```